# "Would you mind if I write X?" vs. "Would you mind if I wrote X?"

Tags: grammar

What is the correct tense of the verb "write" if I wanted to ask someone "Would you mind if I [write/wrote] your name on this list?"

Answer (score 3):

To my ears it sounds like "Would you mind if I wrote..?" is more of an "in theory" question, while "Do you mind if I write ..?" is the way you would phrase when standing right next to a sign-up list with your mate and presenting him with an actual choice. Also I don't think it's correct to use "would" + present tense.

Should he confirm the latter question, you're GOING to write his name on the list. Asking "Would you mind if I wrote.." feels like asking someone if he'd generally object or agree to you writing his name on that list.

Anyway: Out of those two choices you gave, the correct one is "Would you mind if I wrote".

Comment: Perhaps use "**Do** you mind if I **write** your name on this list?" instead.  I think that's more grammatical (and now someone is going to yell at me for converting an absolute adjective into a comparative).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "I don't think it's correct to use would + present tense".

Answer (score 2):

> Do you mind if I write...
>
> Would you mind if I wrote...

Comment: Would you mind if I were to write "*Would you mind if I were to write...?*"?

Answer (score -1):

The use of *write* signals a likely event. The use of *wrote* signals a possible event.

> Would you mind if I write your name on this list?...

...because that is what I plan on doing unless you tell me otherwise

> Would you mind if I wrote your name on this list?...

...because I won't unless you tell me to